# I keep getting error of "Property subscribe does not exist on type void "

Tags: angular, angular-material, observable, subscription, subscribe

here is my ts file function which throws the error

post-list.componenet.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.posts = this.postsService.getPosts();
  this.postsSub = this.postsService.getPostUpdateListener()
    .subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
      this.posts = posts});
}


}
```

here is a service file

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostsService {
  private posts: Post[] = [];
  private postsUpdated = new Subject<Post[]>();

  getPosts() {
    return [...this.posts];
  }

  getPostUpdateListener(){
    this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
  }

  addPosts(title: string, content: string) {
    const post: Post = {title:  title, content: content};
    this.posts.push(post);
    this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
  }
}
```

I have imported the 'rxjs' dependency module and I can't seem to identify how to correct the error.
The code runs on the browser but I don't  get the desired output

Comment: I did kill my server and restarted it but I am still getting the same error. I have also checked all the files and I can't find any errors. Is there any other method I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to return your data on your getPostUpdateListener()

```
getPostUpdateListener(){
   return this.postsUpdated.asObservable();
  }
```